# html text inside quotes

Tags: html, text

I am sending a text to a web service. The web service reads the text and makes  a html report. The text is multiline. The web service connects all the lines and makes a single line and then wraps it in a quoted string. I want the text lines  come separately in the html report. I have no access to change or view the web service's code.

---

I tried to add `<br/>` at the end of each message line before sending,  but it didn't work.The browser handles `<br/>` like a normal text and it comes exactly in the report: `line1<br/>line2`.

I look for a trick to get rid of the quotes and allow the browser to interpret the html tags like `<br/>`.

Comment: If the service is secure there won't be way to make it interprete html tags or else it would be easy to perform some kind of code injection

Comment: What about new line chars (`\n`), does it make any change? Also, doesn't web service allows some own method of escaping? There might be some details in the API description.

Comment: There is no way we can tell how a web service that **you have told us virtually nothing about** can be made to give a specific output. What you have said suggests it is impossible, but you need to consult their documentation and technical support, not Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending

```
text = '************ <br/> SomeText <br/>**********';
```

Use

```
html='************ <br/> SomeText <br/> **********';
```

I don't know whether it satisfies your requirement